# invalid_request in angularjs with Laravel + OAuth

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, oauth

I am creating `RESTful` API with `Laravel (BackEnd)` and `AngularJS (Front End)`, I want to implement `OAuth` to secure my API of Laravel.

I've Installed a `OAuth` in my laravel but when i call a request on server from angularjs then it gives error of invalid_request.
Here is my Code :

Laravel Side :

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function() {
    return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
});
```

Angular Side :

```
$http({
    url: $url.siteUrl('oauth/access_token?grant_type=password&username=stafftest&password=password'),
    method: "post",
    headers: {'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I get Error like :

```
{
    "error":"invalid_request",
    "error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the 'grant_type' parameter."
}
```

What is the problem any ideas?

Thanks.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution, I've just added `$.param` in data field `AngularJS`:

```
$http({
    url: $url.siteUrl('oauth/access_token'),
    method: "post",
    data: $.param({client_id:"1",client_secret:"12345",grant_type : 'password', username : 'johndoe', password : 'A3ddj3w'}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Even I was having this problem... And I tried the same... But the console tells me that $url is not undefined... So I removed the complete $url.siteUrl (like this url: 'oauth/access_token')... Then I get another error which tells me $ is not defined pointing to the $ after data:... What should I do now...??

Comment: Have you define Jquery in Your Head part?

Comment: and another thing is that $url.siteUrl is my Custom function, it is not a functionality that provided by angularjs.